# access 2010 - Query adding total for each month

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010

I have a db in access 2010 with a completion date. When I filter the data using a query I get all the fields with the date in mm/dd/yyyy format so I get bunch of January, March etc. What I want to do is only display the total number of records in a particular month so I want the data representation as:

January = 15
February = 10
...

I would appreciate it if someone can help me out with this.

EDIT: OP add it as a comment

```
SELECT ActData.BPManager, ActData.contractorname, ActData.SiteName, 
     ActData.Type, ActData.Adhoc, ActData.TicketCompleteDate 
FROM ActData 
WHERE (((ActData.BPManager)="Sasa Jazic") AND 
    ((ActData.contractorname)="Sovereign Consulting Inc.") AND 
    ((ActData.Type)="PSD Inspection") AND 
    ((ActData.Adhoc)="No"))
```

Comment: Could you share schema and data sample? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have was not able to find a solution to count and display each month total, I just have a sql querry with the filters i use:
SELECT ActData.BPManager, ActData.contractorname, ActData.SiteName, ActData.Type, ActData.Adhoc, ActData.TicketCompleteDate
FROM ActData
WHERE (((ActData.BPManager)="Sasa Jazic") AND ((ActData.contractorname)="Sovereign Consulting Inc.") AND ((ActData.Type)="PSD Inspection") AND ((ActData.Adhoc)="No"));

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Let me know if it works or need some tunning.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month(ActData.TicketCompleteDate) as 'Month', 
       count(ActData.TicketCompleteDate) as 'Cant'
 FROM ActData 
 WHERE (((ActData.BPManager)="Sasa Jazic") AND 
    ((ActData.contractorname)="Sovereign Consulting Inc.") AND 
    ((ActData.Type)="PSD Inspection") AND 
    ((ActData.Adhoc)="No"))
GROUP BY month(ActData.TicketCompleteDate)
```

Comment: I am not sure why but I get wrong counts, any idea why that would be?

Comment: Couple things, as I mentioned before I can not get the correct totals, which might be a problem with my data since the query looks good. On top of that I am trying to add a simple SUM but appears to be that I can not even get that and get an error message: below is the updated query:

Comment: SELECT Month(ActData.TicketCompleteDate) AS ['Month'],
Count(ActData.TicketCompleteDate) AS ['Activit Count'], 
SUM('Activit Count') AS ['Activit Total']
FROM ActData
WHERE (((ActData.BPManager)="Sasa Jazic") 
AND ((ActData.contractorname)="Sovereign Consulting Inc.") 
AND ((ActData.Type)="PSD Inspection") 
AND ((ActData.Adhoc)="No"))
GROUP BY Month(ActData.TicketCompleteDate);